# Deserialize nested array of json object returns null

Tags: java, json, jackson

My Json looks something like (and its unmodifiable)

```
{
    ....
    "Sale": [
        { "SaleLines": {
                    "SaleLine": [
                        {
                            "unitPrice": "190",
                            "unitQuantity": "1"
                        } 
                ], 
            "calcDiscount": "0",
            "calcSubtotal": "500"
        }
    } ]
}
```

The java POJO code looks like

```
public static class SaleLines {

    @JsonProperty("SaleLine")
    private ArrayList<SaleLine> saleLine;

    public ArrayList<SaleLine> getSaleLine() { return saleLine; }

    public void setSaleLine(ArrayList<SaleLine> saleLine) { this.saleLine = saleLine; }
}

public static class SaleLine {
    @JsonProperty("itemID")
    private String itemId;                  //line_item_nk
    @JsonProperty("unitPrice")
    private String unitPrice;
    ....
}

@JsonPropertyOrder({"total", "calcSubTotal", "calcDiscount"})
public static class Sale {

    private String saleTotal, calcSubtotal, calcDiscount; 
    private int salesValueWOVat;

    @JsonProperty("SaleLines")
    SaleLines saleLine;

    @JsonCreator
    public Sale (@JsonProperty("total")String saleTotal,
            @JsonProperty("calcSubtotal")String calcSubtotal,
            @JsonProperty("calcDiscount")String calcDiscount,
            @JsonProperty("SaleLines")SaleLines saleLine,
    ) {
        this.saleTotal = saleTotal;
        this.calcSubtotal = calcSubtotal;
        this.calcDiscount = calcDiscount;
        this.saleLine = saleLine;
        setSalesValueWOVat();
    }

    // getter and setters 

}

@SuppressWarnings({ "rawtypes" })
public static <E, T extends Collection> T readFromJsonAndFillType (
        String json, 
        Modules module,
        Class <T> collectionType,
        Class <E> elementType) 
        throws JsonParseException, JsonMappingException, IOException {

    ObjectMapper objMapper = new ObjectMapper()
        .configure(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES, false)
        .configure(DeserializationFeature.ACCEPT_SINGLE_VALUE_AS_ARRAY, true);

    TypeFactory tf = objMapper.getTypeFactory();
    JsonNode node = objMapper.readTree(json).get(module.jsonFieldName); 
    return objMapper.readValue(node.toString(),
            tf.constructCollectionType(collectionType, elementType));

}
```

In main

```
ArrayList<Sale> saleList = readFromJsonAndFillType(
                saleJSON, 
                Modules.SALE, 
                ArrayList.class,
                Sale.class);

for (Sale sale: saleList) {
    System.out.println(sale.getSaleLines().getSaleLine().size()); //ERROR Null Pointer Exception
    System.out.println(sale.toString());
}
```

So, the problem is that the SaleLine does not get populated as expected

Comment: That doesn't seem to be a valid JSON. `sale` is an array, but what's inside the array is supposed to be an object, and that object is not surrounded by `{}`.

Comment: oops, my mistake. the sale array has {} and I have corrected the question

Comment: You know, if you just parsed into Maps and Lists rather than POJOs you'd be done by now.

Comment: Have you attempted to debug this at all??  You say the "nested array" is null, but what about the outer objects??

Comment: Yes, I have. The elements of Sale pojo can be retreived. The problem starts happening with SaleLines.

Comment: But you name your SaleLines variable `saleLine`, not `saleLines`.  Are you sure you're looking in the right place?

Comment: I am sure its looking at the right place. you are right about the naming, its a bit confusing but thats how it is :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible that your JSON is invalid; e.g. there are commas missing in the latest version in your Question.

If the problem is that your JSON is syntactically invalid, then you will either need to hack the JSON before you parse it or hack the parser to accept invalid JSON.

On the other hand, it is possible that some of your JSON records are missing the `SaleLine` or `SaleLines` attributes or have a `null` instead of one of the values.  If that is possible, add some null tests ... and reject the record or cope with the missing data.

Comment: It's a very simple matter to capture the JSON string and paste it into an online parser such as http://json.parser.online.fr/ to verify the syntax.

Comment: @Stephen C The json provided to me is not invalid it was my mistake while copy pasting it for the question. I have corrected it now. The json provided by me above is an idea of what I have. The problem is what I mentioned in the question or the title

Comment: @LivingThing - have you checked that the array isn't `null` in the source JSON?

Comment: @StephenC Ya, its not null

Comment: You were right, apparently some of the SaleLine were missing, I just missed it while going through the json and that was causing the null. As you menioned now I have to cope with the missing data. Thanks too @HotLicks too